# Playing with hashmap in drawing

Tags: android, libgdx, sprites, performance

I'm developing a game in Java for Android, using LibGDX.
In my render(), between the batch.begin() and batch.end() I'm running through all the game objects and draw them.

Every game object is stored in a list, which that list is stored inside a hash map. I iterate through this hash map, getting every list and going through that list, like this:

```
    batch.begin();
    Iterator it = objectsMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        Array list = (Array) pair.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
            GameObject object = (GameObject) list.get(i);
            drawObject(object);
        }
    }
    batch.end();
```

My drawObject() code:

```
private void drawObject(GameObject object, float x, float y) {
    if (object == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (object.getVisibility()) {
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion currentFrame = object.getCurrentFrame();
        if (currentFrame != null) {
            float objectAlpha = object.getAlpha();
            Color color = batch.getColor();
            if (objectAlpha != 1) {
                color.a = object.getAlpha();
                batch.setColor(color);
            }
            batch.draw(currentFrame, x - object.getOriginX(), y - object.getOriginY(), object.getOriginX(), object.getOriginY(), currentFrame.getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight(), object.scaleX, object.scaleY, object.getSpriteDirection());
            color.a = 1;
            batch.setColor(color);
        }
    }
}
```

A method called setRegion() sets the current animation frames of the object:

```
protected void setRegion(String name, float frameDuration) {
    currentFrame = atlas.findRegion(name, 0);
    if (currentFrame == null) {
        currentFrame = atlas.findRegion(name, -1);
    }
    width = currentFrame.getRegionWidth();
    height = currentFrame.getRegionHeight();
    animationStateTime = 0;
    animation = new Animation(frameDuration, atlas.findRegions(name),      Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
}
```

And in the update() of the objects this is called:

```
            currentFrame = (TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(animationStateTime, isLooping);
```

The getCurrentFrame() method only returns currentFrame variable.
The alpha is a field with a value between 0 and 1. (getAlpha() returns only the field)

My question is that considered a "heavy" activity? Can this be a significant impact on the FPS values? Because I'm running my game on old devices (like Galaxy S2) and the FPS can get pretty low values. I'm trying to find the cause to it.
I used to have a reference to every list but with the time I realized I'm going to have too much lists, so I decided to do it like this. Maybe you know a better way of holding references to all game objects?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly do you draw things? Are you drawing tile based things? Are you drawing things that are off screen? Drawing things usually costs the most memory so you have to minimize the drawing and looping through as efficiently as possible. Sometimes this means you have to sacrifice memory over performance where you for example store a texture to get it directly instead of getting it from a list with a reference.

Comment: I use atlases to draw all images of sprites. The only regular draw of a texture is of the background image.
I edited my question with the method's code.

Comment: Looking up atlasses each frame is not a good way. You are probably better off storing these in the objects. How do you get your X and Y? The method you post desires it but when you use the method you do not supply it.

Comment: And are you drawing tilemaps? Tilemaps can be drawn extremely efficient.

Comment: What is going on in `getCurrentFrame()` and `getAlpha()`? Really hard to say anything about it without the code itself.

Comment: I don't use tilemaps because the levels are not complex. They are supposed to be only a background image and a few objects on the screen. It's not supposed to scroll or anything.

I posted more code pieces above.

Thank you btw!

Comment: How big is your atlas?  Looking up regions each loop is not efficient.  Store the regions in a list and look them up by Index Id. If you click "goto definition" at atlas.findregion you can see documentation above the method telling you should store the results.

Comment: I will make a edit when back, later in the evening.

Comment: But I don't call findRegions each loop and I don't call setRegion each loop, only when object is created or changing a set of images.

I use an atlas for each character (each character has a set of images) so the heaviest atlas file is 83 kb.

Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26262/discussion-between-gad-wissberg-and-menno-gouw).

Comment: Sure but I'm not behind my pc right now.  Perhaps later in the evening.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what a hashmap does is store the objects in a random location in your memory. Complexity is O(1) which means that it will always take the same amount of time to retrive an object from the hashmap. The amount of time depends on various factors. This might be quite fast for few objects, but as soon as you start drawing scene with hundreds of objects, I would consider a hashmap as very poorly performing (poor FPS as a result).
The reason for that is simple. Your memory has to go to get the object from a different location for every object. A more performant approach would be to store all objects right next to each other in memory (which in turn would be a very bad hashmap), so that you could go on where you left off in memory. Depending on the device and your application, this might as well be a major performance gain.
Also take a look at the Entity-Component-System, [this article](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html) about data locality (which is the specific answer for this very question) and also all other articles on [gameprogrammingpatterns.com](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html). You might be able to improve other parts of your code as well :)

Comment: Thank you for the highlights, I will take a deep look in those docs!
But I guess it's not supposed to affect it much because the objects are actually located inside the arrays, not inside the hash map. The hash map only holds references for the arrays.

If I go back creating reference for every array without hash map, do you think it'll have a significant effect on performance?

Comment: Ah, ok, I got you wrong, sry. Hashmaps certainly have an additional overhead. How big the impact on performance is, is hard to guess. You would have to benchmark the application with and without hashmaps to see the difference.